# Django Add object Count and Raw SQL in Javascript

Tags: django, django-templates

```
def dashboard(request):
employee = Employee.objects.count()
position1 = Posit.objects.raw('SELECT employee.stat, count(posit.position_id) as NO FROM employee, posit WHERE employee.id = posit.employee_id AND posit.position_id="1" GROUP BY employee.stat')

context = {
    'employee ': employee ,
    'position1': [pos for pos in position1] ,
    
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', context)
```

I can use employee count inside the javascript. `var x = JSON.parse("{{employee}}")`. How do I add position1 into a variable in javascript.

Because when I add `var y = JSON.parse("{% for pos in position1 %}{{pos.NO}}{% endfor %}")`.

I got this error

`Invalid block tag on line 96: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Here is the whole error

```
86  
87              }
88          }
89      };
90      window.onload = function () {
91          window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"), config);
92      };
93      var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);
94  </script>
95  
96  {% endblock %}
97  {% block content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave a space between the curly braces:

`{{ pos.NO }}`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I played with the Javascript and tried to write it in one line. I just disable the html beautifier and write it in 1 line and it finally works.